# How is Newton's method rearranged to express the numerical method for finding cube roots?

Tags: calculus

Newton's Method is given as:

$x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$

Newton's method modified to find the cube roots of a number $a$:

$x_{i+1}=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{a}{x^2_i}+2x_i)$

How is Newton's Method used to achieve the latter equation?
Here's my pathetic attempt:

Let $f(x_i) = x^3-a$

$x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$

$x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{x^3_i-a}{3x^2_i}$

$x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{1}{3}(x_i-\frac{a}{x^2_i})$

$x_{i+1}=x_i+\frac{1}{3}(\frac{a}{x^2_i}-x_i)$

???

Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: You're sooo close. Just write $x_i = \frac{1}{3}(3x_i)$ and incorporate it into the parenthesis.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean just substitute every $x_i$ with $\frac{1}{3}(3x_i)$?

Comment: $x_{i+1}=x_i+\frac{1}{3}(\frac{a}{x^2_i}-x_i)=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{a}{x^2_i}+2x_i)$ if you expand and rearrange.

Comment: well, I'm an idiot. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You've done well so far, all that is missing is the last small step:

$$\begin{align}
x_{i+1} &= x_i + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{a}{x_i^2} - x_i\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{3}(3x_i) + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{a}{x_i^2} - x_i\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{a}{x_i^2} + 3x_i - x_i\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{a}{x_i^2} + 2x_i\right).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks so much. I can't believe how simple it was just to factor the single $x$ into the parenthesis. Sometimes the simplest algebra eludes me, did you know I spent 3 hours trying to figure out the last step?

Comment: Familiar story. The easy things, you either see immediately, or not at all before you took a sufficiently long break.